# Excel 2016 conditional formatting not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

For some reason the above conditional formatting rule does not working and I have no idea why.

Can anyone provide an oppinion?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, maybe your cells already had a fill color? What if you try applying the same to a fresh worksheet?

Comment: Cannot replicate this error with my Excel 2016... Might be what @A.S.H mentioned.

Comment: The same happens if I paste the data in a new worksheet. I don't have an existing fill color.

Comment: I can't replicate it either. Doing what you did correctly formatted for me.  I posted a slight alternative though.

Comment: I can replicate what you did as well in a new sheet but if I copy/paste the columns to the new sheet I get the same thing.

Comment: You must have text inside those cells, not numbers. Changing the format wont fix it. To verify it, try entering by hand a number < 50 in one of those cells, what happens?

Comment: @A.S.H looks like it's working that way. But that data is imported from a csv file. What do I do now?

Comment: Use the method suggested by @BruceWayne but the formula `=NUMBERVALUE(G1)>85`

Comment: Thanks everyone. That worked. How do I split up points between you guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try being more specific.  Use `=G1>85`, and apply to the range instead.

[image]

Comment: I get the same thing. I don't have any other rules applied to this worksheet.

Comment: @Iulian - Hmmm...Close Excel **completely**, perhaps even restart your computer. Then reopen to a NEW workbook and do a quick test. You can use data such as `=Randbetween(0,200)` to get data filled in, then try.  Also, perhaps post (in your OP) any formulas that are returning those results.

Answer (score 0):

Before setting the conditional rule for Fill color:

1. Highlight the area you plan to use to set the conditional fill
   color.
2. Format the area first, with "No fill."
3. Then use conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to select clear all the rules at the conditional formatting tab.